# React, accessing variable defined in componentDidMount from another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a responsive drop down navbar in React and have come to a roadblock. I have these variables defined in componentDidMount

```js
componentDidMount = () => {
        let nav = document.getElementById("topNav")
        let main = document.getElementById("main")
        let menu = document.getElementsByClassName("menuitems")
        let close = document.getElementById("closeBtn")

    
        nav.style.height = "50px";
        main.style.marginTop = "50px";
        for (let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
            menu[i].style.marginTop = "100px";
        };

        close.addEventListener("click", function () {
            const menuIcon = close.children;
            for (let i = 0; i < menuIcon.length; i++) {
                menuIcon[i].classList.toggle("active");
            }
        });
    }
```

and I am attempting to access them in an onClick function on the same react component here

```js
navToggle = () => {
  console.log(this.nav)
}
```

the variable is logged as undefined.

So, my question, how can I access variables that are defined in the compnentDidMount?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variabled defined within the scope of `componentDidMount` will stay within that function itself. You need to assign them to the class instance like

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.nav = document.getElementById("topNav")
    this.main = document.getElementById("main")
    this.menu = document.getElementsByClassName("menuitems")
    this.close = document.getElementById("closeBtn")


    this.nav.style.height = "50px";
    this.main.style.marginTop = "50px";
    for (let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        this.menu[i].style.marginTop = "100px";
    };

    this.close.addEventListener("click", function () {
        const menuIcon = this.close.children;
        for (let i = 0; i < menuIcon.length; i++) {
            menuIcon[i].classList.toggle("active");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That was it also, I had to change the function in addEventListener to an anonymous function call. Thank you!